# Given quadratic integral relations for $y$ and $z$, find explicit integral relations for $y+z$ and $yz$

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

> $A$ $\subset$ $B$ is a ring extension. If $y,z \in B$ satisfy quadratic integral dependence relations $y^2+ay+b=0$ and $z^2+cz+d=0$ over $A$, find explicit integral dependence relations for $y+z$ and $yz$

I used the hint provided and assumed that $1/2 \in A$, and used the quadratic formula for obtaining $y$ and $z$. Then I calculated $y+z$. After a really cumbersome calculation (trivial though) I managed to obtain an integral relation for $y+z$. However, for $yz$, I think there should be an easier way because even for $y+z$, which includes two square roots the calculation was long. I appreciate any solution or hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be interested in the resultant construction.  **It's main advantage is that it generalizes to arbitrary integral relation degrees (where explicit factoring gets ugly fast) while keeping all of your computations in $A$**.  To my knowledge, there is no such comparable method for the product of integral elements.

Let $f = \sum_{i=0}^{n} f_i x^i, g = \sum_{j=0}^m g_j x^j$ be polynomials in $A[x]$.

> The resultant $Res_x(f(x), g(x))$ of two polynomials is defined as $$Res_x(f(x), g(x)) = f_n^n g_m^m\prod (\alpha_i -\beta_j)$$ where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ range over the roots of $f$ and $g$, respectively.

(N.B. you can always find a ring extension of $B$ in which $f$ and $g$ totally factor, since they are monic, even if $B$ is not a domain.  See Bourbaki's Commutative Algebra early Chapter V or a standard reference on integral dependence for details.  Of course in a domain the algebraic closure of the quotient field will do).

A fundamental property of the resultant is that it is also the determinant of the Sylvester Matrix of $f$ and $g$, i.e. the $(n+m) \times (n+m)$ matrix

$$\begin{bmatrix}
f_n & \cdots & f_0 & \\
\ddots & & \ddots & \\
 & f_n & \cdots & f_0 \\
g_m & \cdots & g_0 & \\
\ddots & & \ddots & \\
 & g_m & \cdots & g_0
\end{bmatrix}$$

Now let $a,b \in B$ be integral over $A$ with respective integral relations $f,g \in A[x]$.

We'll show that the resultant $h = Res_z(f(z), g(x-z))$ is a monic polynomial in $A[x]$ such that $h(a+b) = 0$

We compute $$h = \prod (\alpha_i + \beta_j - x)$$  Since $a = \alpha_i, b=\beta_j$ for some $i,j$, it is clear that $h(a+b)= 0$, and that $h$ is monic (though you might adjust for sign).  Meanwhile we can see that $h$ is a polynomial in $A[x]$ from the determinant of Sylvester Matrix characterization, so $h \in A[x]$ is indeed an integral relation for $a+b$.

An advantage to working this way is that all of your computations to produce $h$ remain in $A[x]$, and in your case of quadratic dependences, calculating the determinant of a $4 \times 4$ matrix is not so bad.

**You can do something similar to get an integral relation for the product of integral elements.**  We only needed the Sylvester's Matrix determinant characterization of the resultant to show that computations can stay in $A$.  You could also take a different approach and argue that the resultant is a symmetric polynomial in $\alpha_i$ and $\beta_j$ and use [Vieta's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_polynomial#Relation_with_the_roots_of_a_monic_univariate_polynomial) (which work for any polynomials with regular leading coefficient!!) to demonstrate that the resultant is a polynomial in $A[x]$.

This arguments transfers just as well to the polynomial $\prod_{i,j}(x-\alpha_i \beta_j)$, which is therefore an integral relation for $ab$.

Answer (score 1):

Write $yz\cdot\begin{pmatrix}1\\y\\z\\yz\end{pmatrix}= A\begin{pmatrix}1\\y\\z\\yz\end{pmatrix}$, where $A$ is a $4\times 4$-matrix whose entries depend on $a,b,c,d$ (one can easily calculate this). Now one can observe that $yz$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, hence it annuls its characteristic polynomial. The same can be done for $y+z$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $y=y_1$, $y_2$ the roots of the first equation and $z=z_1$, $z_2$ the roots of the second equation. Then $x=y+z$ is a root of
$$(X-(y_1+z_1))(X-(y_1+z_z))(X-(y_2+z_1))(X-(y_2+z_2))$$
Expand and express the coefficients of this polynomial in terms of $a$,$b$, $c$, $d$.

If you just want a quick result, use elimination with Groebner bases and some software. The result is fairly long, an equation of degree $4$ in $x$. See results with WA [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=CoefficientList%5BGroebnerBasis%5B%20%7By%5E2%20%2B%20a%20y%20%2B%20b,%20z%5E2%20%2B%20c%20z%20%2B%20d,%20x-(y%2Bz)%7D,%20%7Bx,a,b,c,d%7D,%20%7By,z%7D%5D,x%5D).